# R S4 class inherited methods do not get loaded on first call, but work on the second

Tags: r, methods, r-s4

I want to learn OO programming in R, and as an exercise I'm writing a small set of functions and methods for reading and writing Fortran namelists. I'm a complete noob at this, so please be kind to the example below (which you can just copy-paste).

I have the following class definitions:

```
setClass("NamelistValue")
setClassUnion("NamelistValue", c("numeric", "character"))
setClass("Namelist",
        representation(group = "character", variable = "character", value = "NamelistValue", comment = "character", file="character"),
        prototype(group = NA_character_, variable = NA_character_, value = NA_real_, comment = NA_character_, file = NA_character_)
        )
```

And for example these methods for replacing the data:

```
setMethod("[<-", c("Namelist", "character", "character", "NamelistValue"),
    function (x, i, j, ..., value) {
        if (length(i) > 1 | length(j) > 1) stop("Cannot subset with more than one index")
        l <- which(x@group==i)
        v <- which(x@variable[l]==j)
        vals <- x@value
        vals[l][v] <- value
        initialize(x, group=x@group, variable=x@variable, value=vals, comment=x@comment, file="<None>")
    }
)

setMethod("[<-", c("Namelist", "missing", "character", "NamelistValue"),
    function (x, i=NULL, j, ..., value) {
        if (length(i) > 1 || length(j) > 1) stop("Cannot subset with more than one index")
        v <- which(x@variable==j)
        vals <- x@value
        vals[v] <- value
        initialize(x, group=x@group, variable=x@variable, value=vals, comment=x@comment, file="<None>")
    }
)
```

Now I set up an object:

```
a <- new("Namelist", group="pippo", variable="ears", value=2, comment="Hi!")
```

And let's look at the methods with `showMethods(class = "Namelist")`, here's the output:

```
Function: [<- (package base)
x="Namelist", i="character", j="character", value="NamelistValue"
x="Namelist", i="missing", j="character", value="NamelistValue"

Function: initialize (package methods)
.Object="Namelist"
    (inherited from: .Object="ANY")
```

Looks fine. Now I try to replace some values with `a[,"ears"] <- 4` and **the command fails**:

```
Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, , "ears", value = 4) : 
  argument "i" is missing, with no default
```

However, **if I try again a second time the same command succeeds**... and I see from `showMethods(class = "Namelist")` that some additional methods have been created/inherited:

```
Function: [<- (package base)
x="Namelist", i="character", j="character", value="NamelistValue"
x="Namelist", i="missing", j="character", value="NamelistValue"
x="Namelist", i="missing", j="character", value="numeric"
    (inherited from: x="Namelist", i="missing", j="character", value="NamelistValue")

Function: initialize (package methods)
.Object="Namelist"
    (inherited from: .Object="ANY")
```

Why is this? Why doesn't it work in the first place, but only in the second try? How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you have methods for `[` as well as `[<-`? This may be to do with the fact that these are internal generics, but to be honest I am not very sure...

Comment: The example in the question is a MRE, so nothing other is done in the R session.

Answer (score 0):

(I don't have the source code for R, so happy for someone who does to edit this. `[<-` is internal, so I can't see its code only its documentation.)

Internal generics do some checking of their own before dispatching methods, and this includes evaluating all arguments in the signature (including `i`). So your first call failed because `i` had no default value to fall back on (the method hadn't been registered yet). However, the default method had got far enough to register that an S4 method existed, so when the call exited the method had already been registered.

This can be seen by looking at `showMethods("[<-")` before and after the first call. Afterwards, despite the error, it shows the inherited methods.

The second call had a pre-registered method, and so called that directly because the signature matched exactly. That saw the default of `NULL` for `i` and used it as desired, and the generic for `[<-` was never called, hence we don't see the error any more.

I thought `selectMethod` might register the methods in a similar way without an error, but apparently it doesn't. Possible workarounds might be:

- write separate methods for each subclass of `NamelistValue` (yuck!)
- use an explicit `""` instead of a missing argument: `a["","ears"] <- ...` --- this will not cause an error, have minimal side effects and register the methods necessary. The trouble is you have to do it for character and numeric separately:

  a["","ears"] <- 4
  a["","ears"] <- "ears!"

That should cover all inherited methods, though I appreciate it isn't ideal...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that you mean, can you provide an example? The one in the question is a MRE, so you can just copy-paste it.

Comment: made an edit to hopefully make things clearer, having made a few experiments of my own...

Comment: Sorry I can't be more help; I was hoping there would be a function like `registerMethods` that registered the methods without actually calling them. Internal generics are funny beasts...

Comment: It just occurred to me that this might be something to do with the fact that argument matching for `[<-` doesn't follow the usual rules, so maybe signatures don't work as normal?

Comment: I do not know, any way to test? I really am a complete noob in S3/4 programming.

Comment: Not sure --- if that is the case, I can't think of a solution in any case!